# How to gather data from array elements in one element based on element attribute with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Looks really simple, it would be 4-5 lines with any language. I am really stuck!
What I already have:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad078cc43c90bb8118b457b"),
    "totalTime" : 323,
    "qData" : [ 
        {
            "qId" : "123456",
            "weight" : 38
        }, 
        {
            "qId" : "654321",
            "age" : 21
        },       
        {
            "qId" : "123456",
            "age" : 14
        }, 
        {
            "qId" : "654321",
            "height" : 122
        }, 
        {
            "qId" : "654321",
            "weight" : 34
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad084cc43c90bb8118b4583"),
    "totalTime" : 312,
     "qData" : [ 
        {
            "qId" : "123456",
            "weight" : 42
        }, 
        {
            "qId" : "654321",
            "age" : 21
        },       
        {
            "qId" : "123456",
            "age" : 15
        }, 
        {
            "qId" : "654321",
            "height" : 124
        }, 
        {
            "qId" : "654321",
            "weight" : 40
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad0853143c90bf4088b457b"),
    "totalTime" : NumberLong(20),
     "qData" : [ 
        {
            "qId" : "123456",
            "weight" : 48
        }, 
        {
            "qId" : "654321",
            "age" : 22
        },       
        {
            "qId" : "123456",
            "age" : 19
        }, 
        {
            "qId" : "654321",
            "height" : 162
        }, 
        {
            "qId" : "654321",
            "weight" : 39
        }
    ]
}
```

And where I need to go. This is just gathering data from within `qData` array for each `document`, based on `qId` of each element. Documents (records) do not mix their data (qData) at all.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad078cc43c90bb8118b457b"),
    "totalTime" : 323,
    "qData" : [ 
        {
            "qId" : "123456",
            "weight" : 38,
            "age" : 14
        }, 
        {
            "qId" : "654321",
            "age" : 21,
            "height" : 122,
            "weight" : 34
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad084cc43c90bb8118b4583"),
    "totalTime" : 312,
     "qData" : [ 
        {
            "qId" : "123456",
            "weight" : 42,
            "age" : 15
        }, 
        {
            "qId" : "654321",
            "age" : 21,
            "height" : 124,
            "weight" : 40
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad0853143c90bf4088b457b"),
    "totalTime" : NumberLong(20),
     "qData" : [ 
        {
            "qId" : "123456",
            "weight" : 48,
            "age" : 19
        }, 
        {
            "qId" : "654321",
            "age" : 22,
            "height" : 162,
            "weight" : 39
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to do this with aggregation framework. Already tried $filter, with $map or  $addToSet, already spent 10 hours on it. Cannot find the right combination.

update: I forgot to mention, I run on 3.4 so `$mergeObjects` is not an option without update.

Comment: I also tried a few combinations with $unwind but it gets too complicated since I need NOT to mix records data. Seems a double $group of some kind, I keep trying but cannot get there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.6.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$qData"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"id":"$_id","qId":"$qData.qId"},
    "totalTime":{"$first":"$totalTime"},
    "mergedata":{"$mergeObjects":"$qData"}
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id.id",
    "totalTime":{"$first":"$totalTime"},
    "qData":{"$push":"$mergedata"}
  }}
])
```

For 3.4 you can use below query.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$qData"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"id":"$_id","qId":"$qData.qId"},
    "totalTime":{"$first":"$totalTime"},
    "arraydata":{"$push": {"$objectToArray":"$qData"}}
  }},
  {"$addFields":{"arraydata":{"$arrayToObject":{
     "$reduce":{
       "input":"$arraydata",
       "initialValue":[],
       "in":{"$concatArrays":["$$this","$$value"]}}
   }}}},
   {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id.id",
    "totalTime":{"$first":"$totalTime"},
    "qData":{"$push": "$arraydata"}
  }}
])
```

Comment: thanks, I appreciate. Forgot to mention I run on 3.4. $mergeObjects is cool but I wonder if I could do it without an update.

Comment: Yw. Added  3.4 edit. We just need to recreate the mergeobjects with objectToArray, concatArrays and arrayToObject.

Comment: @JohnPan if this solved your problem, please accept/upvote the answer.

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla of course I will, as soon as I try the solution. Veeram 's answer is great

Comment: Your answer worked great, thanks again. I am surprized that '$arrayToObject' worked with 3.4 while they say it is new in 3.6, which is why I did not even try to solve it this way... https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/

Answer (score 0):

One little thing to get the best out of @Veeram's answer. Going Veeram's way will also produce some noise like:

```
        {
            "qId" : "123456",
            "qId" : "123456",
            "weight" : 48,
            "age" : 19
        }
```

So the way I fixed this was to add `$setUnion` while reducing the array:

```
 $reduce : {
           input:"$arraydata",
           initialValue:[],
           in:{ $setUnion : {$concatArrays:["$$this","$$value"]}}
 }
```